# django DateField model -- unable to find the date differences

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I'm unable to find the difference between two dates in my form.

```
models.py:
  class Testing(models.Model):
        Planned_Start_Date = models.DateField()
        Planned_End_Date = models.DateField()
        Planned_Duration = models.IntegerField(default=Planned_Start_Date - Planned_End_Date)
```

difference between the date has to calculated and it should stored in the database but It doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

`default` is a callable function that is just used on the class level, so you can't use it to do what you want. You should override the model's `save()` method (or better, implement a `pre_save` signal handler to populate the field just before the object is saved:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.Planned_Duration = self.Planned_End_Date - self.Planned_Start_Date
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

But why do you save a computed property to the database? This column is unnecessary. Both for querying (you can easily use computed queries on the start and end date) as for retrieving, you're wasting db space.

```
# if you need the duration just define a property
@property
def planned_duration(self):
    return self.Planned_End_Date - self.Planned_Start_Date

# if you need to query tasks which last more than 2 days
Testing.objects.filter(Planned_End_Date__gt=F('Planned_Start_Date') + datetime.timedelta(days=2))
```

Note: Python conventions would recommend you name your fields using snake_case (`planned_duration`, `planned_end_date`, `planned_start_date`). Use CamelCase for classes (`TestingTask`). Don't mix the two.